# converting a char* to BSTR* which contains special characters

Tags: char, character, bstr

I'm trying to convert a `char*` to a `BSTR*`, and my `char*` has special characters in it from being encrypted.  I have tried several approaches found on the web, but back in the calling vb code, I always end up with something different.  I'm pretty sure this has to do with the special characters, because if I don't have them in, it seems to be ok....

my code is something along these lines...

```
_export myFunction(BSTR *VBtextin, BSTR *VBpassword, BSTR *VBtextout, FPINT encrypt) {

BSTR password = SysAllocString (*VBpassword);
char* myChar;
myChar = (char*) password  //is this ok to cast? it seems to remain the same when i print out.

//then I encrypt the myChar in some function...and want to convert back to BSTR
//i've tried a few ways like below, and some other ways i've seen online...to no avail.

_bstr_t temp(myChar);
SysReAllocString(VBtextout, myChar);
```

any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to interface VB with C code?

Comment: Yes...exactly....the VB code is calling the C code...then back to the VB code.

Comment: did you get the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're manipulating the buffer, you probably don't want manipulate the `char *` directly.  First make a copy:

```
_export myFunction(BSTR *VBtextin, BSTR *VBpassword, BSTR *VBtextout, FPINT encrypt) {

  UINT length = SysStringLen(*VBpassword) + 1;
  char* my_char = new char[length];
  HRESULT hr = StringCchCopy(my_char, length, *VBpassword);
```

If that all succeeds, perform your transformation.  Make sure to handle failure as well, as appropriate for you.

```
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    // Perform transformations...
  }
```

Then make a copy back:

```
  *VBtextout = SysAllocString(my_char);
  delete [] my_char;
}
```

Also, have a read of [Eric's Complete Guide to BSTR Semantics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx).